# cache to not repeat something from .json

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

is there a way to use the cache to keep something from .json not being repeated?

for example: in .json there are 5 messages

[

"hi"

"hello"

"hiii"

"test"

"OK"

]

I wanted it to start repeating only when the 5 options were already used

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const textest= require('../test.json')
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

var rand = textest[Math.floor(Math.random() * textest.length)];

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setDescription(rand)
  await message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a table, for example:

```js
var words = [];
```

And then push every word that has been used into that table.
An example of this would be:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const textest= require('../test.json');
var words = [];

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

var rand = textest[Math.floor(Math.random() * textest.length)];
if (words.length >= textest.length) words = [];
if (words.length === (textest.length - 1)) words = [];
if (words.length > 0 && words.includes(rand)) rand = textest[Math.floor(Math.random() * textest.length)];

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setDescription(rand)
  await message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Comment: why would you mark it as the answer if its not the answer

Comment: i adjusted, but I think I will not find an answer to that